# Angular route guard not calling return

Tags: angular, angular-router-guards

I have an auth class set up like this:

```js
export class AuthService {
  user = new Subject<string>();

  login(name: string) {
    this.user.next(name);
  }

}
```

I have an auth guard set up to check to see if my user subject has a value like this:

```js
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

    return this.authService.user
      .pipe(
        map(user => {
          const isAuth = !!user;
          if (isAuth) {
            return true;
          }
          return this.router.createUrlTree(['/login']);
        })
      );
  }
}
```

I put print statements in the return and they never get called. The page never loads and it never re-directs either. If I just return true or false it works but by returning my authService.user nothing seems to happen.

Comment: Could you please post the entire content of your guard?

Comment: @RafiHenig I updated my question with the full class.

Comment: is auth always false why are you use `const isAuth = !!user;`  !!user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apparently issue with your currently code is that no part of your app is pushing any data into `user subject` when subscribing to it in your guard.

How about using [`BehaviorSubect`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/behaviorsubject.html) so that when ever you subscribe to it you'll accept a value? using `BehaviorSubect` unless you push into it a new value you'll accept the initial value right away when subscribing to it.

```js
export class AuthService {
   user = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);

   login(name: string) {
     this.user.next(name);
   }
}
```

Comment: I am subscribing and reading this value on another component without any issue so the Subject is being populated correctly.

Comment: What do you get  in map when debugging?

Comment: If I add a console log in the map it never gets called.

Comment: Try BehaviorSubect, as it contains the old value in it  as opposed to a regular subject where you only get the value if you were subscribed to it when it's been sent the new value.

Comment: I agree, try BehaviorSubject or ReplaySubject. Subject will only emit NEW values, but if you subscribe to it it will NOT emit any existing values